# How do i know someone who is participating in the hurdle in Slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am currently using the Slack API.

What i need is information about whether a particular person is participating in a hurdle in Slack.

[users.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info) API provides information about the user, but does not seem to provide information about the huddle.

Is there a way?

Thank you!